# How often can a B1/B2 visa holder visit the USA?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, repeat-visits

I'm holding a B1/B2 visa. My last visit to the USA was 3 months ago and I have stayed in the US for 1 and a half months. That means I visited the US in May and stayed till end of June. Then am I allowed to visit the US again in October? This time I'm only planning to stay for a week.

But I have planed to revisit next year in January and May. All these visits will be for a week or one and a half weeks.

Is this allowed with a B1/B2 visa? Is there a particular time period that I need to stay from my last visit to next visit?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is allowed.  The major restriction is that you cannot use the B-2 visa to reside in the US.  If you do that, you can expect that at some point an immigration inspector will refuse entry.

However, you're not coming remotely close to that in terms of the amount of time you plan to spend in the US.  There is no explicit restriction on the frequency of visits, and the duration is typically limited, as you have already seen, to six months.